# iOS Streaming mp3

Tags: ios, objective-c, streaming

I've been searching for a good tutorial for playing and streaming audio finally I found [this](http://www.ymc.ch/en/building-a-simple-audioplayer-in-ios) which seems to offer an offline audio playing.

in the YMCAudioPlayer class I've commented loading a resource and provided NSURL* generated by a direct link instead like so.

```
- (void)initPlayer:(NSString*) audioFile fileExtension:(NSString*)fileExtension
{
    //NSURL *audioFileLocationURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:audioFile withExtension:fileExtension];
    NSURL *audioFileLocationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://188.95.64.47/AghaninaDownload/Content/per_singer/JFire/Audios/J-FirE_and_Omar_khalid_wlaKelmeh-sample.mp3"];
    NSError *error;
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];
}
```

And I've ensured that it's a valid link, but seems not to play on emulator. what have I missed there?

**EDIT**

It generates the following error

```
 Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)
```

Comment: Why don't You download the mp3 on disk while streaming hope this helps you https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002273-BCIJHAGD

Comment: Isn't there a direct stream method instead of download and play?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the answer in [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618744/how-to-handle-error-code-43-from-nsosstatuserrordomain-when-initializing-avaudi)

"I was able to fix the issue by loading the file first into an NSData element and then using that to initialize the AVAudioPlayer instead, like so:"

```
NSData *songFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:songCacheURL options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error1 ];
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:songFile error:&error2];
```

Comment: That is a horrible solution and you wont be streaming at all using this variant. Not even a progressive download playback. Switch to `AVPlayer` instead of `AVAudioPlayer` as the latter does not support HTTP streaming but the former does.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a stupid question, but did you make it play ?

[self.audioPlayer play];

Then I would try this, to ensure your settings are correct :

```
[self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

[self.audioPlayer setCurrentTime:0.0];

[self.audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];

[self.audioPlayer play];
```

You can also use the delegate of AVAudioPlayer to check if something happens when you play.

Else it might be an URL of format issue.

Comment: play is called on a button

Comment: maybe you should print the error in your init error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot play audio on EMULATOR, you have to test it on device.

Here mentioned on apple developer guid -

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1

Comment: Is that true? do you have a resource?