# Can't stream radio from online url iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mp3, internet-radio

I want to stream online radio from URL in my iOS application, but it works only when I put the path of an mp3 file added to my project and doesn't work for the online mp3 url, here is my code, any ideas please? or do you have a good tutorial on how to stream online files, I saw many tutorials but all of them talk about local mp3 files

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
AVAudioPlayer *_audioPlayer;
 }
 @end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Construct URL to sound file
//NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/drum01.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]; // here when I uncomment the line it works fine
NSString *path = @"http://fileadress.mp3"; // here it doesn't work, it's an available link and I'm testing it on the simulator
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

// Create audio player object and initialize with URL to sound
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playSoundTapped:(id)sender
{
// When button is tapped, play sound
[_audioPlayer play];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

"AVAudioPlayer does not support streaming via HTTP. Try using AVPlayer instead."

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6095568